# Cannot extend the processes list while attaching the debugger for NodeJs projects

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I use VSCode to work on several NodeJS projects. In order to debug them, I normal have an "Attach by Process ID" entry in my launch.json file.
When I try to pick the process I want to debug, the displayed list isn't wide enough to show the entire path of the process. This is very annoying as I need to be trying one after the other is other to discover what process does my app use.
[image]

On the other hand, there seems to be no way to extend that part of the screen.

Any workaround on this will be much appreciated!